# How to open a second WPF window on startup

Tags: wpf, window

I would like to display a messagebox or second window on top of the main window at the time the main window opens without user doing something.  This is more or less a reminder message/window to the user to do something.  Once closed by the user control should go back to the main window.  The method below opens before the main window is open, which doesn't help.

```
    private static void CheckHomePosition()
    {
        if (LocalSystem.MountType != 0 && !TelescopeHardware.AtHome) return;
        var homeDialog = new HomeDialogWindow
        {
            Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
            ShowInTaskbar = false
        };
        homeDialog.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: Where is `CheckHomePosition` called from?

Comment: I've tried multiple spots all within MainWindow(). also tried a Loaded += Window_Load; no luck

Answer (score 0):

A WPF `Window` provides a `ContentRendered`event for cases like this. You can just override the `OnContentRendered` method within your window.

```
protected override void OnContentRendered(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnContentRendered(e);
    CheckHomePosition();
}
```